# 3 JLabel's on the Same Line When I Use <br>

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

When a user runs this program they are prompted to enter their name, address, and telephone number. I want to display all 3 of these things on separate lines, but even though I use the HTML break line they are all still displayed on the same line... Help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;

public class Info {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String address;
        String number;

        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
        address = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your telephone number: ");
        number = scan.nextLine();

        JFrame Information = new JFrame();
        Information.setTitle("Information");
        Information.setSize(300, 200);
        Information.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        Container pane = Information.getContentPane();
        pane.add(panel);
        Information.setVisible(true);
        JLabel nameL = new JLabel("<html><br>" + name + "</br></html>");
        panel.add(nameL);
        JLabel addressL = new JLabel("<html><br>" + address + "</br></html");
        panel.add(addressL);
        JLabel numberL = new JLabel("<html><br>" + number + "</br></html>");
        panel.add(numberL);
        Information.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think that BR tag works in this way?

Comment: 1. I'm new Java 2. I've seen it being used this way in examples on this website 3. You don't need to be a jerk because I'm new to programming...

Comment: @user2803082: please don't jump to conclusions. He is not being a jerk, and you are assuming a bit much in how components work and what Lashane is saying. Never guess, but instead read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML only works on a single JLabel's text and won't work as a layout manager for multiple labels. Instead do just that, use a layout manager such as GridLayout to allow you the accepting JPanel to stack the JLabels.

i.e,.

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1)); // for 1 column, multiple rows
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(label2);
panel.add(label3);
```

---

**Edit**
links:

- [Layout Manager Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [GridLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: I don't know how to do GridLayout. Can you help!?

Comment: @user2803082: just did. But also, you will want to read the tutorials and API since that's a skill that will get you a lot further than us giving you exact code solutions.